# Google Login Integration Issue

Tags: android

I have developed app with Google login integration. It is working fine. So,   I have signed apk file and upload into Google Play Store without any issue. I have downloaded from Play Store Now, Google Login Integration is not working. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used the debug key store file to generate SHA-1 hash key.

if you are going to publish to play store.
You need to create OAuth 2.0 client ID using release key store SHA-1 hash key and
get JSON file and replace it.

[Google Signin](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

Comment: keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias <key alias name > -keystore <generated app key store path>